# How to display a sidebar TOC for all parts in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, read-the-docs, tableofcontents

Maybe it is just me, but I often have a hard time to understand and navigate
Sphinx based documentation, because the Table Of Contents only shows the 
structure of the *current* page (in the standard themes at least).

There is also a `previous` and `next`, but what I really would like to see is
a TOC in the sidebar that shows *all* parts, with the current part expanded.

For example the main page (i.e. index.rst) would be 'Overview' and opened by
default. Introduction and Quickstart are Sections of index.rst:

```
Overview
    Introduction
    Quickstart
    Credits
Tutorial
Contribute
Index
API
Search
```

'Tutorial' would be offered as `next`.
When the 'Contribute' item is selected, the TOC is updated like so:

```
Overview
Tutorial
Contribute
    Install for development
    Style Guide
Index
API
Search
```

`Search`, `Index`, `API` should link to the generated pages, that are typically
inserted like this in the Sphinx tutorials:

```
Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this on [Read the Docs](http://readthedocs.org/), 
or can anyone point to existing templates?

Comment: This might help: http://sphinxcontrib-fulltoc.readthedocs.org